# Que formato de url me recomiendan para usar en AJAX/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

tengo funciones como la de insercion de datos en la DB que lo hago a través de AJAX, mi problema es que cuando pongo la url, lo pongo con www  y http, me funciona en chrome y en Firefox, pero no en IE ni Opera. A que es debido esto?

Aqui os dejo el codigo AJAX:

```
$("input[name='enviar_login']").click(function(){
        var datos = $(".formulario_login").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"http://ejem.com/login/login.php",
            data:datos,
            success:function(result){
                if (result=="") {
                    $(".login p").css({
                        "background":"rgba(255,0,0,.2)",
                        "border-radius":"10px 10px 0 0"
                    });
                }else if(result!=""){
                    $(location).attr("href","http://ejem.com/login/" + result);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
});
```

Funciona en Firefox y Chrome pero no en IE ni en Opera

Gracias.

Comment: Podrías probar otras formas de redirigir como window.location.assign("http://ejem.com/login/" + result)

Comment: Prueba a usar rutas relativas. Es decir: url : "hola.php" si el archivo hola.php esta en el mismo directorio, url:"saludos/hola.php" si el archivo se encuentra en un subdirectorio llamado saludos y "../" para ir subiendo directorios ("../.." y asi..)

Comment: Se puede de alguna manera ir a la raiz del htdocs con rutas relativas? sin usar $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], que no existe en jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola la solucion es esta:

```
        $("input[name='enviar_login']").click(function(){
        <?php $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>
        var datos = $(".formulario_login").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo $root; ?>/login/login.php",
            data:datos,
            success:function(result){
                if (result=="") {
                    $(".login p").css({
                        "background":"rgba(255,0,0,.2)",
                        "border-radius":"10px 10px 0 0"
                    });
                }else if(result!=""){
                    window.location.assign("<?php echo $root; ?>/login/" + result);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Lo que hago es que la variable php, la paso a javascript, y cuya varaible coge el path raiz de mi web.